# Can't find configured AuditLog domain error while configuring Auditlog plugin for Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, logging, audit

I am trying to add the auditlog plugin but when server stars I get the error Cant find configured Auditlog domain and the server shuts down.

```
    [ERROR] 2015-11-10 15:22:04,561        org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEventController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEventController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find configured AuditLog domain: groovy.util.ConfigObject@5bb5d623
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEventController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEventController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find configured AuditLog domain: groovy.util.ConfigObject@5bb5d623
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEventController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find configured AuditLog domain: groovy.util.ConfigObject@5bb5d623
```

And this is how I added in the my buildconfig.groovy

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
    compile ":audit-logging:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the docs (http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/audit-logging), you must perform

`grails audit-quickstart your.package.YourAuditLogEvent>`

to create the audit-log Domain class in your project and to configure this class in Config.groovy.

BTW: 1.1.0 is released, already.

Comment: I have dont the same, `// Added by the Audit-Logging plugin:
auditDomainClassName = 'com.backface.AuditLog'`  but still I am getting 100 % the same error.  _Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find configured AuditLog domain: groovy.util.ConfigObject@2b072e3c_  still I think the application cannot read the domain file name from Config.groovy

Comment: Please check if the format is similar to the one in the test application:https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/blob/1.x_maintenance/audit-test/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L126

Comment: There was an error in the documentation on plugins.grails.org. Correct quickstart syntax is:  

    
    grails audit-quickstart <your.package.name> <YourAuditLogEventClassName>  
    

Ensure the domain class is created within grails-app/domain with the correct package name.